# C# EF Query optimisation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following function using entity framework, that checks a db table for expired product data, the entire query seems extremely slow and i am wondering if there is a better / more efficient way of adapting this query as there is always a bulk amount of data to clean sometimes upto 3k items.

It is purely the selection item that can take 4-10 mins dependant on db size on the day.

Datetime format Example = 2021-03-31T23:59:59.000

```
using (ProductContext db = new ProductContext())
{
    log.Info("Checking for expired data in the Product Data db");
    //rule = now - configured hours, default = 2 hours in past.
    var checkWindow = Convert.ToInt32(PRODUCTMAPPING_CONFIG.MinusExpiredWindowHours);
    var dtCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-checkWindow).ToString("s"));

    var rowData = db.ProductData.Where(le => Convert.ToDateTime(le.ProductEndDate.Value.ToString().Trim()) < dtCheck).ToList();

    rowData.ForEach(i => {log.Debug($"DB Row ID {i.Id} with Product ID Value: {i.ProductUid} has expired with Product End Date: {i.ProductEndDate}, marked for removal."); });

    log.Info($"Number of expired Products being removed: {rowData.Count()}");

    db.ProductData.RemoveRange(rowData);
    db.SaveChanges();

    log.Info(rowData.Count == 0
        ? "No expired data present."
        : $"Number of expired assets Successfully removed from database = {rowData.Count}");
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT::**

Thanks to all the suggestions i will be looking at the ORM comments made by Panagiotis Kanavos below in regard to direct queries for this type of item and amended the column datatype based on the comment from Panagiotis Kanavos again. Finally the .ToList comment by jdweng removed the lag immediately so this at least gets my moving faster for now while i look at the suggestions by Panagiotis Kanavos as i think that is probably the best way forward?

Faster code is now:

```
using (ProductContext db = new ProductContext())
{
    log.Info("Checking for expired data in the Product Data db");
    //rule = now - configured hours, default = 2 hours in past.
    var checkWindow = Convert.ToInt32(PRODUCTMAPPING_CONFIG.MinusExpiredWindowHours);
    var dtCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-checkWindow).ToString("s"));

    // Ammended DB Table from nvarchar to DateTime to allow direct comparison based on comment by: Panagiotis Kanavos
    // Removed ToList() which returned the IEnumerable immediately based on comment by: jdweng
    var rowData = db.ProductData.Where(le => le.ProductEndDate < dtCheck);

    log.Info($"Number of expired Products being removed: {rowData.Count()}");

    // added print out on debug only.
    if(log.IsDebugEnabled)
        rowData.ToList().ForEach(i => {log.Debug($"DB Row ID {i.Id} with Product ID Value: {i.ProductUid} has expired with Product End Date: {i.ProductEndDate}, marked for removal."); });


    var rowCount = rowData.Count();

    db.ProductData.RemoveRange(rowData);
    db.SaveChanges();

    log.Info(rowCount == 0
        ? "No expired data present."
        : $"Number of expired assets Successfully removed from database = {rowCount}");
}
```

So grateful to all the useful comments below and grateful for the time you all took to respond and help me learn from this.

Comment: The query looks fine to me. It may be the problem of your DB, how do you build the index for the table? Are you saying you're deleting 3k rows at once?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe there are 10's k rows a day and often a bulk load upto 3k toward end of month may expire at once. generally though its around a couple of hundred which can sometimes be slow

Comment: Is `ProductEndDate` a `DateTime` column in the database? There seems to be some unnecessary string conversion going on in your code

Comment: @Alex-TinLe the query isn't fine at all. First, it tries to filter data by *converting* a date field to a string and then back to a date. That alone results in a full table scan. Then it tries to delete that data - why load anything at all in that case?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. We can't tell, because he may put the column as string type.

Comment: @Psymon25 3K is a tiny amount of data. What this code does though is inappropriate for an ORM. First, it tries to filter by converting dates to strings, forcing a full 10K row table scan without indexing. Then it tries to delete items one by one

Comment: @Alex-TinLe that's even worse and still results in a full table scan. We *can* tell that this query is inappropriate

Comment: thanks all so far i will check the db column type and update to reduce the scan time

Comment: @Psymon25 if you want to delete everything before a certain date write a parameterized DELETE query, eg `DELET ProductData Where ProductEndDate<@date`. Using an ORM in this case is inappropriate - there are no Objects to Map to Relational tables

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for this i am not a seasoned dev by far still learning so happy to look at the advice you have provided thus far, i will change the column type on lab and test and look at the parameterised query instead

Comment: @Psymon25 this code converts dates to strings all over the place. There's no reason to use `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-checkWindow).ToString("s"))`. This will only return the value returned by `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-checkWindow)`. The query should be `db.ProductData.Where(le => le.ProductEndDate<dtCheck)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks i updated the test code to var rowData = db.ProductData.Where(le => Convert.ToDateTime(le.ProductEndDate < dtCheck).ToList(); and altered the table which oddly (not my db) was stored as a string. Now the checkWindow conversion i left for a moment as thats a string value from a file.

Comment: What version of EF is being used here? If its below 3.0 I suspect the query is evaluating locally which would reduce performance greatly.

Comment: Removing the ToList() will speed up the query.  What database are you using?  Using a Stored Procedure will speed up code.  Check Task Manager while query is running and check the amount of free memory.

Comment: @KieranDevlin ef 6

Comment: @jdweng i will check this too along with the previous orm / parameterised query suggestions

Comment: @jdweng .tolist did it straight away :D although i take on the points about the ORM model too from Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: You can use this method to run a sql `DELETE` statement https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @mortb nice one thank you for this thats super useful